# java arrays and inputs

Tags: java, arrays

How do u write to a next array index by modifying this code? I'm a noob at java. for e.g, I am  calling this method from my main method, so the first time it is run, it writes to index 1 of the array. the second time it is run, it writes to index 2 of the array. however, I do not want it to loop. I have also not learnt arraylists' yet so its out of the picture unfortunately.

```
public class staffName {
  public static void staffDetails(){
       String[] staffname= new String[20];
       int i=0;
       staffname[i]=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please enter staff name:")
       i++;
```

}

Comment: Just move the variable outside the function then repeatedly call the function if you don't want to loop..?

Comment: you can use a while loop if you dont want to use a for loop but the run time is the same

Comment: Each time you call `staffDetail`, a new array is created and then thrown away, so which index you write to won't make that much difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting variable i everytime you call a function to 0. So you only change element 0 all the time. You need to put variable i outside a function and make it static so it increments when you call the function and stays incremented.
You also must put array staffname outside, otherwise, you make new empty array everytime you call a function.

```
public class staffName {
    public static int i = 0;
    public static String[] staffname= new String[20];

    public static void staffDetails(){
        staffname[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please enter staff name:");
        i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the Array only once in the main and do it like this:

```
public class staffName {
private static int i = 0;
String[] staffname= new String[20];
 public static void staffDetails(String[] array){

    array[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please enter staff name:")
    i++;
 }
}
```

Comment: You're ignoring the `array` argument.

Comment: which Array Argument?

Comment: Now you have added a `staffname` array as an instance field and you're ignoring that.

Comment: Yes because I forgott to Change it but now it should work

Answer (score 0):

> calling this method from my main method, so the first time it is run, it writes to index 1 of the array. the second time it is run, it writes to index 2 of the array.

Problem is both array and index loses its scope once the method `staffDetails()` does its job.

Option 1: Consider sending array and index as parameter

```
public static void staffDetails(final String[]staffname, final int i){
       staffname[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please enter staff name:");
}

public static void main(String[]args){
    final String[]staffname=new String[20];
    int i = 0;
    staffDetails(staffname,i++);
    staffDetails(staffname,i++);
}
```

Option 2: Make array and index as class/static members

```
public static void staffDetails(){
       staffname[i++] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please enter staff name:");
}

public static void main(String[]args){
    staffDetails();
    staffDetails();
}

private static final String[]staffname=new String[20];
private static int i = 0;
```

Comment: I think you will get the same error as he gets. First time you write on Position 1 second time you write on Position 2 and so on

Comment: @user12346352, what makes you think that the [code](https://ideone.com/yevIT4) generates error?

Comment: Not directlayan error but i think if you call the function with i++ then you store the first Input on the Position 1 of the error and the second Input on Position 2 of the error. Or Am I wrong About that?

Comment: @user12346352, it would be helpful to you when you run and test code by yourself.